# Slider animation not running smooth FF12

Tags: jquery, animation

In the latest chrome, I see the animation running smooth, but in Firefox, the animation looks really bad.

This is my source code, maybe something causes it to load slower:

```
jQuery.fn.Slider = function(Options) {
    var Settings = {
        Width: 900,
        Height: 400,
        Speed: 400
    }
    var SliderSettings = $.extend(Settings, Options);
    var View = $('.slider_view');
    var Images = View.children();
    var CurrentImage;
    var LeftButton;
    var RightButton;
    var Animation = false;

    var Controls = $(this).append('<div class="controls"></div>');

    var NumOfImages = Images.size();

    if (NumOfImages > 1) {
        Controls.append('<div class="slider_leftBtn"></div><div class="slider_rightBtn"></div>');
        LeftButton = $('.slider_leftBtn');
        RightButton = $('.slider_rightBtn');
        LeftButton.hide();
        CurrentImage = 0;
    }

    $(RightButton).click(function() {
        if (!Animation) {
            Animation = true;
            View.animate({ 'left': (parseInt(View.css('left')) - SliderSettings.Width) + 'px' }, SliderSettings.Speed, function() { Animation = false; });
            LeftButton.fadeIn();
            if (++CurrentImage + 1 == NumOfImages)
                RightButton.fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $(LeftButton).click(function() {
        if (!Animation) {
            Animation = true;
            View.animate({ 'left': (parseInt(View.css('left')) + SliderSettings.Width) + 'px' }, SliderSettings.Speed, function() { Animation = false; });
            RightButton.fadeIn();
            if (--CurrentImage == 0)
                LeftButton.fadeOut();
        }
    });
};
```

Is there any action in my code that can cause FF to animate that way?

This is a small slider I wrote, nothing special.

**UPDATE:**

The next setting causes FF to run slowly:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px 20px #000;
```

How can I still maintain that effect?

Comment: That's just how it is. Chrome is always bragging about how fast javascript executes in their browser and rightfully so. Try http://html5bookmarks.com in chrome and firefox. Make the window skinnier and wider and watch the modules move around the page. You'll notice the same difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using -moz-transform:translate(x,y)
It's hardware accelarated.